# How to check if more children exists in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have sort of this structure :

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="a">
      <input class="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo $user['fname']; ?>" />
      <input class="lname" type="text" value="<?php echo $user['lname']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <span class="update">Update</span>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="a">
      <input class="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $user['email']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <span class="update">Update</span>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="a">
      <input class="dob" type="text" value="<?php echo $user['dob']; ?>" />
    </div>
<span class="update">Update</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to read the value from the text field via jQuery. I am able to get the first children of `a` class using when `update` was clicked : `$(this).siblings('.a').children('input').val()`

I'm not sure how to get the other value if update for full name is clicked. I have to grab both `fname` and `lname` in that case. If I can check if more children exists then grab next's value? Confused!

Thanks for help in advance.

EDIT

Here is what i am upto :

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(event) {
    var newval = $(this).siblings('.a').children('input').val();
    alert(newval);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this out,

```
var fname = $(this).siblings('.a').children('input.fname').val();
var lname = $(this).siblings('.a').children('input.lname').val();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kej2u/)

If you want to get all the values, then try using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$(".update").click(function(){

    $(this).siblings('.a').children('input').each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/kej2u/1/)

Comment: Yes that is the thing. But i'm trying to get the value onclick in just 1 callback function to click. But in your way i can just take these 2 values. What about other values such as email, if update to email is clicked?

Comment: @Cruze oh you want to grab all the values in a single click.?

Comment: and that should depend on number of input fields i have in a div, like in first div i have 2 inputs - fname and lname but in latter i just have 1 to read.